# Windows - Software restriction policy to block exe files in all subdirectories

Tags: windows, windows-7, group-policy

How can I block all executables in %APPDATA%?

I've read for CryptoLocker this is a good policy:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\*\*.exe
```

But that apparently won't protect more than one layer deep.

But what's to stop someone from going another layer deep like `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\dir\dir\trojan.exe`

Is it possible to create a policy that blocks every exe in appdata no matter how deep?

How do you handle these issues? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Microsoft's guidance on GPO Software Restriction:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx

> **Path Rules**
>
> A path rule can specify a folder or fully qualified path to a program.
>   When a path rule specifies a folder, it matches any program contained
>   in that folder **and any programs contained in subfolders.** Both local
>   and UNC paths are supported.
>
> Using Environment Variables in Path Rules.
>
> A path rule can use
>   environment variables. Since path rules are evaluated in the client
>   environment, the ability to use environment variables (for example,
>   %WINDIR%) allows a rule to adapt to a particular user's environment.
>
> Important: Environment variables are not protected by access control
>   lists (ACL). If users can start a command prompt they can redefine an
>   environment variable to a path of their choosing.
>
> Using Wildcards in Path Rules. A path rule can incorporate the '?' and
>   '*' wildcards, allowing rules such as "*.vbs" to match all Visual
>   Basic® Script files. Some examples:
>
> •"\\DC-??\login$" matches \\DC-01\login$, \\DC-02\login$
>
> •"*\Windows" matches C:\Windows, D:\Windows, E:\Windows
>
> •"c:\win*" matches c:\winnt, c:\windows, c:\windir

So since a user can just redefine where %APPDATA% points to, consider using the `APPDATA` environment variable in your path rule, instead of the actual fully-qualified file system path.

[More documentation:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786941%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> The following examples show instances of applying environment variables
>   to a path rule:
>
> • “%UserProfile%” matches C:\Documents and Settings\User and **all subfolders** under this directory.
>
> • “%ProgramFiles%\Application” matches C:\Program Files\Application
>   and **all subfolders** under this directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this. Even when using %APPDATA% instead of a direct system path, unless you make a rule per each sub folder (/asterix/, /asterix/asterix/, /asterix/asterix/asterix/) and so on for how ever deep you want it to go, windows will stop enforcing when it goes past the depth you defined.

I tested this by putting a self contained auto clicker into the AppData/roaming directory, and then tested it by adding a folder and moving the exe deeper into the file structure. After going past 3 levels deep, as defined in the Local security policy, Windows allowed the auto clicker to run.

Comment: In 2022, with Windows 10 21H2, I cannot confirm your finding. I just tested it, and it worked as expected on my machine. But please note that my rule pattern was `c:\folder1\folder2`, not `c:\folder1\folder2\*.exe`. As far as I understand, Microsoft guarantees only the first one to include subfolders. I didn't test the second one.